# Finding a constant $B > 0 $, so that $\left\lVert x \right\rVert$ $\leq$ $ B* \left\lVert x \right\rVert_\infty$

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces, constants

How do I find a constant $B > 0 $, so that $\left\lVert x \right\rVert$ $\leq$ $ B* \left\lVert x \right\rVert_\infty$ works for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

I am not sure but I think I have to look at $x$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_ie_i$  with the development of the x to the canonical unit vectors $e_i$. But how do I do that formally?

Comment: What is your definition of $\|x\|$?

Comment: Its defined as the norm of a vector (the one that satisfies the axioms non-negativity, positive-definiteness, positive homogeneity and subadditivity). Basically finding this constant is part of a bigger task where one has to prove step-by step that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, which can be done by proving that every norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equivalent to the chebyshev distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $x = x_1 e_1 + \cdots + x_n e_n$.
If $\|\cdot\|$ is an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb R^n$ you have
$$\|x\| = \|x_1e_1 + \ldots x_n e_n\| \le \sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i e_i\| = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \|e_i\|.$$
Each $x_i$ satisfies $|x_i| \le \|x\|_\infty$ so that $$\|x\| = \|x_1e_1 + \ldots x_n e_n\| \le \sum_{i=1}^n \|x\|_\infty \|e_i\| = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n  \|e_i\| \right) \|x\|_\infty. $$ Take $$B = \sum_{i=1}^n  \|e_i\|.$$